# Express Node.js mvc vs .NET mvc architecture

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js, express

My question is :

Are routers.js files in express framework of nodejs any different from the codebehind (aspx.cs) pages in c# .NET or both concepts are same ?

If they are different why and if they are same is it practical to give every view page its own router because we definitely can use one router.js file to route all the pages, for example using in index.js can work

```
router.get('/allusers/user/:name', function(req, res){}
```

Comment: The schema may be the same, in fact it can be whatever you want. It has nothing to do with MVC nor Node.

Comment: Using .net with mvc the best practice would be to separate the codebehind from the business logic and call the logic files as your controllers, So if we are talking about node best practices what is the best approach?